# How to write a query to exclude all employees of a department that have at least one person of the age 30 in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to exclude all departments where staff is of the age 30.
[image]

As per the above table, I should get all employee details except the HR department as HR has an employee of the age 30 years.

Below is what I tried. I'm getting HR also in the output and unable to get all details in the select query.

```
select dep from emptest
where age not in (30)
 group by dep
```

Comment: Hint: `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @Filburt haha apologies for the mistake in the data.

Comment: You need to exclude the whole HR dept because it has someone with age > 30? Or you only need to exclude the person who is older than 30?

Answer (score 0):

use subquery:

```
select
*
from emptest
where department not in
(
   select department from emptest where age = 30
)
```

Comment: Depending on the RDBMS and your data at hand, this approach can bear a risk - back in the days, Oracle had a magic number of max 1000 elements allowed in an `IN` set.

Comment: Wow, was not aware of that - thanks! Mostly I work with MSSQL. Have good one!